# Host '1.2.3.4' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server -

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, connection

I'm working on a Debian 10 based server, which has a perfectly running MariaDB instance. However for testing purposes, I want to start another service (to test clustering with other servers, without tweaking the original service...etc). I named this "mariadb@test.service", I also added a new config file for it (and created an empty datadir folder, which has the mysql user as owner):

**/etc/mysql/conf.d/mytest.cnf**

```
[client-server]
socket=/tmp/mysql-test.sock
port=3307

[client]
password=PASSWORD

[mysqld]
user = mysql
datadir=/var/lib/mysql-test
skip-bind-address
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
```

The service runs without errors, but I have one problem: I cannot connect to it remotely. However I **can** connect to the main service which is running on 3306. Of course in the `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` the "bind-address" line is commented out, so I can connect to the server from another computer (via DBeaver in my case).

Both mariaDB instances have the "same" configs:

- root user is granted all privilages on localhost
- dedicated user is granted all privilages on @localhost as well as on @%
- priviliges were flashed, multiple times
- in any config file I either commented out the bind-address or added the skip-bind-address command
- neither of them has the skip-network activated
- they both run on the same server on the same IP, but with different (open and free) ports (3306/3307)

I compared the `mariadb.service` file to the `mariadb@.service file`, there's no difference about the interfaces. The mariadb@ service should not include any other config file (not like it would matter, since as I said the main service can be remotely connected to). I don't think there's any config file left which I didn't checked.

What am I missing?

*Edit*
So to clear things up: the problem is that I cannot connect to this mariaDB server with eg. DBeaver. It always gives the error `Host '1.2.3.4' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server`. There's no network problem as I know, I can ssh to that computer (in place or via VPN), the server doesn't have any firewall on it. Th service seems to run OK, the settings in DBeaver are the same (except the port), configs are almost the same between the two services, the server doesn't show any specific error message about not connecting.

Answer (score 0):

Check what ports are listened on your server.

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

Also check firewall settings to be sure port 3307 is open for incoming connections (iptables or ufw).

Comment: Both ports are said to be open by the command you wrote:


mysqld    2098 mysql   29u  IPv4  32100      0t0  TCP *:3306 (LISTEN)
mysqld    2189 mysql   21u  IPv4  31341      0t0  TCP *:3307 (LISTEN)


(Also, netstat shows the same.) Since this is a test server on the local network, it doesn't have any firewall rule for these ports. Both services are active and don't show any errors.

Comment: Can you login to mysql localy and check permissions?
SHOW GRANTS FOR username;

Comment: Grants for NAME@%
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `NAME`@`%` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'PASS'  WITH GRANT OPTION

(This is the same as on the other, main service BTW.)